# How do i make the lines break properly in a <pre> with a width?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<pre>` tag that needs to have a width and a height. For some reason, whenever the text goes beyond the contents of the `<pre>`, the lines do not break, and the text carries on. How do I rectify this?

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/k45cJ/

Comment: Why are you using `<pre>` if you want it to wrap? You kind of only use `<pre>` when you *don't* want that to happen.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen you might also use pre if you just don't want whitespace to collapse.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using css:

```
<pre class="wrapped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</pre>

pre.wrapped {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: +1 Please note the browser compatibility of `pre-wrap`: http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/white-space:pre-wrap

Comment: This will work though It think it would be better to change `<pre>` to `<div>`